# Alguna manera de hacer mas "elegante" esto?

Tags: java, eficiencia

Voy a explicar mi situación rápidamente, tengo una función que devuelve 0,1 o 2 dependiendo de las 4 funciones que están adentro, dichas funciones devuelven 0, 1 o 2. Ahora bien, la manera que tengo implementado el algoritmo es esta:

```
public int ganador() {
    
    if(ganadorFilas()>0) {
        return ganadorFilas();
    }
    else if(ganadorColumnas()>0) {
        return ganadorColumnas();
    }
    else if(ganadorDiagonal()>0) {
        return ganadorDiagonal();
    }
    else if(ganadorDiagonalesContinuas()>0) {
        return ganadorDiagonalesContinuas();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es: Puedo implementar dicha funcionalidad de una mejor manera?

pd: había pensado en usar el Math.max(x,y) sucesivamente para solucionar esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo haría 2 cosas:

1 - Eliminar los `else` puesto que son innecesarios.

```
public int ganador() {
    
    if(ganadorFilas()>0) {
        return ganadorFilas();
    }
    
    if(ganadorColumnas()>0) {
        return ganadorColumnas();
    }
    
    if(ganadorDiagonal()>0) {
        return ganadorDiagonal();
    }
    
    if(ganadorDiagonalesContinuas()>0) {
        return ganadorDiagonalesContinuas();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

2 - Guardar el resultado de cada método en una variable, para luego comprobar su valor y, si procede, retornarla. Esto evita llamar dos veces al mismo método, lo que es ineficiente.

```
public int ganador() {
    
    int ganaFilas = ganadorFilas();
    if(ganaFilas > 0) {
        return ganaFilas;
    }
    
    int ganaColumnas = ganadorColumnas();
    if(ganaColumnas > 0) {
        return ganaColumnas;
    }
    
    int ganaDiagonal = ganadorDiagonal();
    if(ganaDiagonal > 0) {
        return ganaDiagonal;
    }
    
    int ganaDiagonalesContinuas = ganadorDiagonalesContinuas();
    if(ganaDiagonalesContinuas > 0) {
        return ganaDiagonalesContinuas;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

**BONUS**: Si quieres también puedes eliminar las llaves de los `if` y subir los `return` a la misma línea de su correspondiente `if`.

```
public int ganador() {
    
    int ganaFilas = ganadorFilas();
    if(ganaFilas > 0) return ganaFilas;
    
    int ganaColumnas = ganadorColumnas();
    if(ganaColumnas > 0) return ganaColumnas;
    
    int ganaDiagonal = ganadorDiagonal();
    if(ganaDiagonal > 0) return ganaDiagonal;
    
    int ganaDiagonalesContinuas = ganadorDiagonalesContinuas();
    if(ganaDiagonalesContinuas > 0) return ganaDiagonalesContinuas;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no hace falta declarar una variable por cada llamada, con una basta (la variable se podria llamar `gana`).. Tambien la asignacion se la podria hacer directamente en el `if`..

Comment: Si, pero para alguien que está empezando considero que es mucho mejor definir una variable para cada escenario posible. Respecto a la asignación dentro del propio `if` no me gusta porque hace el código más difícil de leer (cuestión de gustos).